# List or OutlineGroup expanded by default in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, ios14, macos-big-sur

With List or OutlineGroup in SwiftUI how to make some (or all) of their branches expanded by default when creating the view. This seems to be possible with DisclosureGroup with a binding.

This could be useful for restoring state or customizing the view for presentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reusable version of `OutlineGroup`, where expandability is under control.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NodeOutlineGroup<Node>: View where Node: Hashable, Node: Identifiable, Node: CustomStringConvertible{
    let node: Node
    let childKeyPath: KeyPath<Node, [Node]?>
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        if node[keyPath: childKeyPath] != nil {
            DisclosureGroup(
                isExpanded: $isExpanded,
                content: {
                    if isExpanded {
                        ForEach(node[keyPath: childKeyPath]!) { childNode in
                            NodeOutlineGroup(node: childNode, childKeyPath: childKeyPath, isExpanded: isExpanded)
                        }
                    }
                },
                label: { Text(node.description) })
        } else {
            Text(node.description)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NodeOutlineGroup(node: data, childKeyPath: \.children, isExpanded: true)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Self { self }
    var name: String
    var children: [FileItem]? = nil
    var description: String {
        switch children {
        case nil:
            return " \(name)"
        case .some(let children):
            return children.isEmpty ? " \(name)" : " \(name)"
        }
    }
}

let data =
  FileItem(name: "users", children:
    [FileItem(name: "user1234", children:
      [FileItem(name: "Photos", children:
        [FileItem(name: "photo001.jpg"),
         FileItem(name: "photo002.jpg")]),
       FileItem(name: "Movies", children:
         [FileItem(name: "movie001.mp4")]),
          FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
      ]),
     FileItem(name: "newuser", children:
       [FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
       ])
    ])

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Very nice, Paul B., thank you.
But I would like to have more control about the displayed rows. So I have expanded your solution a little bit:

```
struct NodeOutlineGroup<Node, Content>: View where Node: Hashable, Node: Identifiable, Node: CustomStringConvertible, Content: View {
    let node: Node
    let childKeyPath: KeyPath<Node, [Node]?>
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = true
    let content: (Node) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        if node[keyPath: childKeyPath] != nil {
            DisclosureGroup(
                isExpanded: $isExpanded,
                content: {
                    if isExpanded {
                        ForEach(node[keyPath: childKeyPath]!) { childNode in
                            NodeOutlineGroup(node: childNode, childKeyPath: childKeyPath, isExpanded: isExpanded, content: content)
                        }
                    }
                },
                label: { content(node) })
        } else {
            content(node)
        }
    }
}
```

with usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NodeOutlineGroup(node: data, childKeyPath: \.children, isExpanded: true) { node in
                Text(node.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for this as well and I believe OutlineGroup doesn't support this. Instead I've moved to DisclosureGroup, which OutlineGroup uses for it's implementation, and directly supports an expansion boolean binding as well as allowing nesting:

```
struct ToggleStates {
    var oneIsOn: Bool = false
    var twoIsOn: Bool = true
}
@State private var toggleStates = ToggleStates()
@State private var topExpanded: Bool = true

var body: some View {
    DisclosureGroup("Items", isExpanded: $topExpanded) {
        Toggle("Toggle 1", isOn: $toggleStates.oneIsOn)
        Toggle("Toggle 2", isOn: $toggleStates.twoIsOn)
        DisclosureGroup("Sub-items") {
            Text("Sub-item 1")
        }
    }
}
```

Example from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup

Answer (score 0):

This is nice, but doesn’t allow for selection. Instead, the subtree under each first level item is composited as a single cell, which makes individual selection impossible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).